# Date are preserved even after clear filter in Magento 2 UI grid

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, uicomponent, ui-grid

On the order grid, I have applied the 'Purchase Date' filter which is working fine.
But after press the  'Clear all' link and apply the filter again.

[image]

**The date is preserved in date related filter (See below).**

[image]

I am sure this will be occurring with all the date filter in all Magento UI grid.

Well, How can I, remove the date value after clear the filter?

Thanks

Comment: any update on this

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the file:

> root/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/js/grid/filters/chips.js

you can update the following function:

```
    /**
     * Calls clear method on all of its' children.
     *
     * @returns {Chips} Chainable.
     */
    clear: function () {
        _.invoke(this.elems(), 'clear');

        return this;
    }
```

To the following changes:

```
    /**
     * Calls clear method on all of its' children.
     *
     * @returns {Chips} Chainable.
     */
    clear: function () {
        _.invoke(this.elems(), 'clear');
        [].forEach.call(
            document.getElementsByClassName("_has-datepicker"),
            function (el) {el.value = ''}
        );

        return this;
    }
```